# raspberry pi camera different white balance

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I made a module that makes 360 degree photos. When I trigger a photo at the same time, with the same script on two different RPis with cameras, the white balance is different. I set the auto white balance to 'off' and set the constant value of white balance gains, but when I check the photos, the white balance is very different. Value between abw_gain which I set and output awb_gain is different too. Here's the code and photos:

```
camera.awb_mode = 'off'
camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
camera.drc_strength='off'

camera.awb_gains = (Fraction(453,257),Fraction(247,257))
g = camera.awb_gains
print g, "wb gains #0"
g = camera.awb_gains
print g, "wb gains #1"
```

/*output#0*/ g = (Fraction(451, 256), Fraction(123, 128)) "wb gains #0"

/*output#1*/ g = (Fraction(451, 256), Fraction(123, 128)) "wb gains #1"

Outputs are the same on both cameras.

This image is from the first camera:
  [image: Image from the first camera]

Below is the image from the second camera:
[image: Image from the second camera]

Answer (score 2):

Set the gain manually using the function:

```
cameraObject._set_awb_gains((redgain, bluegain))
```

Parameters can be `integer` or `float` ranging from `0` to `8`.

Comment: Thank you for documenting this here... was about to go check the code, but I was trying to find what the upper limit for the gain value was, and didn't see it documented anywhere else!